# enabling NFS on firewalld for two subnets only

Tags: centos, firewalld

After setting up NFS (use v3) on Centos I had to enable it in firewall:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=nfs 
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=mountd
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=rpc-bind
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Now I need to change it to allow access for NFS clients from two sub-nets only:
192.168.10.0/24
192.168.177.0/24

In addition I need to allow ssh traffic for public zone.

One of this subnets is the subnet where the NSF server is installed in.

I have tried to add both subnets into "trusted" zone and corresponding rules but the zone disappears from active zones after firewalld is reload.

```
# firewall-cmd --get-active-zones
drop
  interfaces: enp0s3 enp0s8
# firewall-cmd --zone=trusted --add-source=192.168.10.0/24
success
# firewall-cmd --zone=trusted --add-source=192.168.177.0/24
success
# firewall-cmd --get-active-zones
drop
  interfaces: enp0s3 enp0s8
trusted
  sources: 192.168.10.0/24 192.168.177.0/24
# firewall-cmd --zone=trusted --permanent --add-service=nfs
success
# firewall-cmd --zone=trusted --permanent --add-service=mountd
success
# firewall-cmd --zone=trusted --permanent --add-service=rpc-bind
success
# firewall-cmd --get-active-zones
drop
  interfaces: enp0s3 enp0s8
trusted
  sources: 192.168.10.0/24 192.168.177.0/24
# firewall-cmd --reload
success
# firewall-cmd --get-active-zones
drop
  interfaces: enp0s3 enp0s8
# firewall-cmd --list-all
drop (active)
  target: DROP
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: enp0s3 enp0s8
  sources:
  services: ssh
  ports:
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to set permanent flag on the following lines :

```
firewall-cmd --zone=trusted --add-source=192.168.10.0/24 --permanent
firewall-cmd --zone=trusted --add-source=192.168.177.0/24 --permanent
```

At the end execute  ( Additional ) :

```
firewall-cmd --runtime-to-permanent
firewall-cmd --complete-reload ## Not to do on production system
```